# How to Concatenate table name with with a variable value in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a dynamic code that would ready from any table with the certain name but the difference between each table name is a number that is generated by a variable: for example :

//that's how I get my variable the value for example is = 3

```
$pid = $GLOBALS["localid"];
```

//the table name for example is tablename_3

```
$strTable = "tablename_" .$pid;
```

//here's how the query should look like

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM . $strTable . where .....;
```

I'm making a mistake somewhere but can't figure it out and would appreciate a little help please

Comment: That is not how you use SQL. Predefine your queries. Don't patch them together!

Comment: echo your query, so that it will easy to find out the issue

Comment: Change your query to this :- `$query = "SELECT * FROM $strTable where .....";`

Comment: Validate the Global variable first and check the quotes, you don't need dots in the double quotes string for a variable. it takes variable as a value `"SELECT * from $table_name where = $value";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the dots and also make sure you have single quotes aroung where

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM $strTable where '.....';
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides the comments about do or don't build your queries like this...

You're not closing the quotes properly.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM . $strTable . where .....; //Double quote not closed.
```

should be:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM' . $strTable . 'where .....'; //Single quoted strings concatenated with variable.
```

or

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM $strTable where ....."; //Variable inside double quoted string.
```